# Why is my raw source code easily accessible via the Debugger's Network tab?

Tags: next.js, sentry

I have been working on my website for a month now and just realized that there is this extra `_N_E` server that is providing access to my raw source code used for each page.

I am using NextJS and suspect that Sentry may be responsible here but I cannot find anything in their documentation about it. This is a risk because not only does this happen in development but in production as well and I do not users to have access to my raw source code.

- Has anyone ever seen this before?
- Can anything be done about it and still get accurate results from Sentry?

[image: sample of network result]

Comment: What's wrong with having access to the raw source code?

Comment: My fear is that someone could download the source code and recreate the website or more easily find vulnerabilities

Comment: Well then it's a good thing that copyright law and licenses exist! And also currently you are relying on security through obscurity; someone could still, with enough effort, find vulnerabilities in the bundled code. I don't think access to frontend source is a problem. It's just a client that interfaces with the server. What you should be concerned about is access to backend source.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/4489) is a ticket describing this problem and how to resolve it.

Make sure to use [@sentry/nextjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/nextjs) >= `6.17.1`.

In your next config file, you want to add the [hidden-source-map](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/#use-hidden-source-map) flag. This boolean will determine if the source map should be uploaded or not. For instance, you may want to conditionally set it for preview deploys.

```js
// next.config.js

const nextConfig = {
  // ... other options
  sentry: {
    hideSourceMaps: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_ENV === "production",
  },
}
```

One thing to note. Previously I was using `v7.6.0` and was able to get the source map files. I have now upgraded to `v7.14.1` and am no longer able to get the source files to display on deploys, regardless of the flags condition. Not sure if this is a regression or just a partially implemented feature.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing sourcemaps publically means anyone (including Sentry) have access

There are two ways you can achieve this

1. Setup a CDN rule that only allows Sentry's servers to get the sourcemaps, a.k.a IP Whitelisting
2. You could upload SourceMaps to sentry - https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/sourcemaps/uploading/